# Argument list too long in Centos after using jpegoptim -m 80 *.jpg

Tags: linux, centos, jpegoptim

I want to compress all jpg files in directory `/var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/mysite_com/_files/photo/` 
using jpegoptim`.

I use code `jpegoptim -m 80 *.jpg` but it shows error **"Argument list too long"**.

Previously I have increased the `ulimit -s 65536` but it still shows **error "Argument list too long".**

Please help me to solve the problem

[image: You can see the screenshot here]

Comment: Asked and answered *ad nauseam*. How is you problem different than the other Q&A's, and why did the answers that tell you to use `find` did not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `find` and `xargs` with `jpegoptim`:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -0 jpegoptim -m 80
```

non-recursive:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -0 jpegoptim -m 80
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
jpegoptim -m80 *.jpg
```

or

```
jpegoptim --max=80 *.jpg
```

If having a large number of file you must use for command like this:

```
for f in *.jpg; do jpegoptim -m80 "$f"; done
```

You should user jpegoptim --help for more information about the use of jpegoptim.

Comment: it still shows error -bash: /usr/bin/jpegoptim: Argument list too long

Comment: It's a kernel limitation on the size of the command line argument. Use a for loop instead:
for f in *.jpg; do jpegoptim -m80 "$f"; done

Answer (score 0):

This example for long list:
for f in /var/www/*/*.*; do jpegoptim  --max=80 --overwrite "$f"; done